# Select query with parameters against WebSQL in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Can I write a simple select query with parameters against WebSQL database using SQL proxy in Sencha Touch 2?

E.g. I would be happy to submit a query to request data for a specific month:

```
SELECT * FROM Expenses WHERE strftime('%m', SubmitDate) = '04'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, after digging into the sources of Sencha Touch SQL proxy, the solution turned out to be using store filters, e.g:

```
Ext.define('Rich.Lite.Web.store.Expenses', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: 'Rich.Lite.Web.model.Expense',
    config: {
        model: 'Rich.Lite.Web.model.Expense',
        proxy: {
            type: "sql"
        },
        filters: [
            {
                property: "strftime('%m', date)",
                value: "04"
            }
        ]
    }
});
```